# Software for Searchable Experiment Archive?

Tags: database, data, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking into software recommendations for a company that has years and years worth of experiments, and it would be really useful to have all that in one archive which could be searched via a query. Currently everything is stored in giant Excel sheets and will have to be reformatted regardless. I'm probably looking for some kind of AI data recall thing, but happy to take any suggestions!

Comment: We need more details. 
If you just upload them to Google Sheet it's already a good starting point. The search bar allows you to search for any term and it might be the answer to your problems